# How do I make the progressBar1 to progress each time by the time I set to timer interval to?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method that i call it from a timer tick:

```
private void NewsUpdate()
{
    counter += 1;

    progressBar1.Value = counter * 10;
    progressBar1.Value = counter;

    label9.Text = counter.ToString();
    label9.Visible = true;

    if (counter == 10)
    {
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
        page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
        TextExtractor.ExtractDateTime(page, newText, dateTime);

        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
        w.Write(page);
        w.Close();

        TextExtractor.ExtractText(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html", newText, dateTime);
        combindedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newText);
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

The `progressBar1` is set from 0 to 100.

I want that if I make:

```
if (counter == 10)
```

Then the `progressBar1` will move to the end after 10 seconds.

If I set it to 50 then it's 50 seconds so the `progressBar1` should move 50 seconds until the end.

The `timer1` in the designer is set to 1000ms

For example now the way it is:

```
counter += 1;

progressBar1.Value = counter * 10;
progressBar1.Value = counter;

label9.Text = counter.ToString();
label9.Visible = true;

if (counter == 10)
```

It will count to 10 the `progressBar1` will move by 10 and then will return to the beginning.

I want to that if I change it to 10 50 or 33 the `progressBar1` will know to move until the end according to the seconds counted.

If its 33 then count 33 and move the `progressBar1` to the end after 33 seconds.

What i want to do is that if i set the IF == 10 then the progressBar will Increment 10 seconds * 10 steps Increment so in 10 seconds the progressBar will get to 100 to the end. Then over again ( this timer is update it should keep running all the time i don't want to stop it i just check if 10 seconds passed make update. And i also want that the progressBar will Increment according to the limit i set in this case 10 untill the end. If its == 10 then the progressBar should Increment each second by 10. And if i set it to == 50 for example then the progressBar should Increment by 2 each s

Comment: Who do you want to do with `progressBar1.Value = counter * 10;         progressBar1.Value = counter;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a counter with *n* steps, where n is the number of seconds to completion.

There are two ways to approach this:

1. (Preferred) Set the `Maximum` property of the `ProgressBar`. This will make everything automatic!

   ```
   counter++;
   progressBar1.Maximum = 33; //This could be set in the designer, or on init
   progressBar1.Value = counter;
   ```
2. Calculate the interval yourself. Do this by dividing the counter by the total number of seconds, then multiplying by the range (100 in this case).

   ```
   counter++;
   progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Round((counter / 33f) * 100);
   ```

All of your other code sounds fine based on your comment.

Comment: @user3739928 Thank you for the clarification, hopefully my new answer helps! You may want to work that comment into your question for future readers.